# Choosing MacOS Mail rich-text link default

Tags: mac, email, links

Since I have updated to MacOS 13, links (urls) I paste in Mail are automatically converted into link previews with an image. This happens when I paste links on a new line.

A little pull down arrow allows me to change the link preview to a "plain link", but the generated preview image remains attached to the email.

Does anyone know how to change this behaviour—would there be a system setting to change this? Ideally I don't even see the option for link previews, but changing the default to paste links as plain links would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by settings -> Composing -> Add link previews.

Note that they have added this recently, but it's present at least in MacOS 14 Sonoma.

For older MacOS versions, setting the message format from Rich Text to Plain Text also removes it.

Comment: Great to see this option now. Thank you for pointing it out! My workaround was to put a . before the link, because I think the previews were only generated for links on new lines. Glad I can stop doing that now.